# Ограничение количества запусков программы

Tags: алгоритм

Можно ли ограничить исполняемый файл по количеству запусков без привязки его к конкретной машине, а так-же без дополнительных файлов?

Например срок службы нашей программы 3 запуска, некий Иван запустил эту программу два раза на своём новеньком ноутбуке, затем скинул исполняемый файл на флеш накопитель и запустил его на своем стареньком компьютере один раз. На четвёртом запуске Ивану будет показано сообщение о том, что его файл исчерпал лимит запусков и больше работать не будет.

Единственное решение которое мне пришло в голову это хранение в каждой программе уникального ключа, который будет передаваться на сервер, который в свою очередь и будет записывать запуски программы. Разумеется для такого метода потребуется наличие интернет соединения, что не всегда может быть удобным. А какие способы создания такой "защиты" вы можете предложить?

Comment: А больше никаких. никто не мешает охранить на флешку изначальную версию exe с тремя запусками. использовать 3 и потом восстановить опять с флешки. а запись куда то на комп сами понимаете так же бесполезна

Comment: Вот всё что тут написано, сводится к одной аббревиатуре - [DRM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2)

Comment: Сделайте из программы сервис в сети - его значительно проще контролировать и гораздо сложнее взломать

Comment: Как вариант защищать с помощью железного устройства, т.е. запускаться только при подключенном usb-токене, на котором собственно и хранится количество запусков

Comment: @Mike, а не дороговато токены с триалами раздавать?

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю, вопросов противодействия взлому программы мы не рассматриваем.

Для решения задачи необходимо существование полностью подконтрольного автору и полностью неподконтрольного клиенту счётчика запусков. Чисто в локальном варианте задача не решается - иначе ставим в виртуалку, делаем снапшот, и реверс к нему после каждого запуска, и так до скончания веков.

Кстати, хранение в экземпляре программы уникального ключа - задача более трудная и неудобная (а про аппаратные ключи в этом смысле даже думать не хочется!), чем просто свободно выдаваемая на определённое количество запусков лицензия. И учёт в этом самом счётчике запусков, оформленном для программы как внешний, но легко доступный, сервис, количества запусков с этой самой лицензией. А по исчерпании разрешённого для этой лицензии количества запусков, если такой лимит установлен - отказ в запуске, возможно, с предложением продления триала на ещё сколько-то запусков или получения новой лицензии.

А теперь представьте на минутку, что программу нужно запускать там, где нет подключения к Инету (или оно таково, что достучаться до сервера учёта не представляется возможным)... знаете, как именно по этой причине попорчена карма у авторов IBExpert?

Comment: Собсн, удивительно, но вы, по сути, повторили всё то, что автор сам итак написал в вопросе))

Comment: Ничего удивительного. Вариантов-то кот наплакал - как реализаций, так и граблей.